# My Polymer Website Fails to provide any Structured Data

Tags: polymer, metadata, google-rich-snippets

If I run https://ahaan.co.uk/article/top_stories/google-releasing-a-new-android-tv-device into the Structured data Tool https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Instead of the article being analysed, my index page is analysed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
    <title>A-hAAn</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="32x32" href="/images/A-hAAn-logo2.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#AA00FF">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="import" href="/src/news-app.html" async="">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #FAFAFA;
            color: #383838;
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
            min-height: 100vh;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        news-app[unresolved] {
            display: block;
            height: 45px;
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            font-size: 39px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        footer {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0;
            text-align: center;
            height: 1em;
        }

        footermobile {
            display: none;
        }

        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            body {
                background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.6) 0%, rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.25) 25%, rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.25) 50%, rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.7) 80%, rgba(103, 58, 183, 1) 100%);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100vh;
            }
            body.fixed-viewport-height {
                background-size: 100% 600px;
            }
            news-app[unresolved] {
                height: 22px;
                padding-top: 21px;
                font-size: 20px;
                color: #FFF;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 800px) {
            footer {
                display: none;
            }
            footermobile {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 0;
                text-align: center;
                height: 2em;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <news-app unresolved="" app-title="A-hAAn">A-hAAn</news-app>
    <footer>
        <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-8720447500483449" data-ad-slot="9510146415" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </footer>
    <footermobile>
        <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-8720447500483449" data-ad-slot="1847278818"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </footermobile>
    <script>
            Polymer = { lazyRegister: !0, dom: "shadow" }, function () { if ("registerElement" in document && "import" in document.createElement("link") && "content" in document.createElement("template")); else { var e = document.createElement("script"); e.src = "/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js", document.body.appendChild(e) } } ();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Where as my Google Engine version https://a-haan.appspot.com/article/androidtv/google-releasing-a-new-android-tv-device will provide data

```
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Daydream brings you on immersive virtual reality adventures powered by a smartphone. Experience it all with Daydream View, a VR headset and controller made by Google available in stores today.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="article-author" content="Ali Hussan Ahmed">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Google has possibly filed another Android TV Device through the FCC">
    <meta property="og:description" content="The Nexus Player has long been discontinued, now Google is ready to make way for a new Android TV device!  I can't say how many threads I've read on Google+ or Reddit that said 'Google has abandoned the Android TV platform' I have to say, I was kinda feeling they had too.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://ahaan.co.uk/data/images/google-fcc-android-tv.jpg">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="A-  <meta property=" og:site_name "=" " og:url"="">
    <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://ahaan.co.uk">
    <meta property="article:published_time" content="2016-11-10">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://ahaan.co.uk/google-releasing-a-new-android-tv-device/">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Google has possibly filed another Android TV Device through the FCC">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="The Nexus Player has long been discontinued, now Google is ready to make way for a new Android TV device!  I can't say how many threads I've read on Google+ or Reddit that said 'Google has abandoned the Android TV platform' I have to say, I was kinda feeling they had too.">
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://ahaan.co.uk/data/images/google-fcc-android-tv.jpg">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@ahaan22">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "mainEntityOfPage": "https://ahaan.co.uk/google-releasing-a-new-android-tv-device/",
    "headline": "Google has possibly filed another Android TV Device through the FCC",
    "datePublished": "2017-02-24T17:00:00+00:00",
    "dateModified": "2017-02-24T06:00:00.434480+00:00",
    "description": "Daydream brings you on immersive virtual reality adventures powered by a smartphone. Experience it all with Daydream View, a VR headset and controller made by Google available in stores today.",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Ali Hussan Ahmed"
    },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "A-hAAn",
        "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://ahaan.co.uk/data/images/google-fcc-android-tv.jpg",
        "width": "200",
        "height": "200"
        }
    },
    "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://ahaan.co.uk/data/images/google-fcc-android-tv.jpg",
        "width": "1440",
        "height": "810"
    }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <div class="uni-paragraph">
                <div class="rich-text">
                    <br>
                    <h2>Android TV is still alive!!</h2>
                    <p>The Nexus Player has long been discontinued, now Google is ready to make way for a new Android TV device!
                        I can't say how many threads I've read on Google+ or Reddit that said "Google has abandoned the Android
                        TV platform" I have to say, I was kinda feeling they had too. That's until Google annouced along
                        side Nvidia that they're planning to roll out Google Assistant to all Android TV devices, that run
                        Android Marshmallow. Which I for one did not expect at all, well done to Google for successfully
                        breaking me down and then building me back up.</p>
                    <h2>Take this with a pinch of salt...</h2>
                    <p>The rumours are that the new Android TV devices will support Google Assistanct out of the Box, not sure
                        if they'll hold the Title of Pixel or Nexus - My money is on Pixel being the name, Google wants to
                        concrete their Pixel brand as much as they can at this point, and they should! The Device will most
                        likely support 4K resolution TV's just like the Nvidia Shield and the Xiaomi Mi box.</p>
                    <h2>The release date is rumoured to be this Spring</h2>
                    <p>Google doesn't seem to be in such a rush to release a new device, I'm counting on the release of the
                        Pixel Android TV device coinciding the release of the roll out of Google Assistant on Android TV,
                        so far the release has been held back even on the Nvidia Shield, that it was first announced with.
                        Be sure to catch a review on my <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/ahaan22">Youtube Channel</a>                        as soon as its ready!</p>
                    <br>
                    <h2>Remember this is just a rumour, check it out for yourself</h2>
                    <a href="https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/ViewExhibitReport.cfm?mode=Exhibits&amp;RequestTimeout=500&amp;calledFromFrame=N&amp;application_id=Lrk60RBJ6f1C60tCFmDScA%3D%3D&amp;fcc_id=A4RGFHD254">Link to the FCC filing</a>
                    <!--image full width-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uni-paragraph">
                <div class="rich-text">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p></p>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <iframe src="../../src/disqus/news-disqus02.html" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0 none;"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use JavaScript to display the content. If you visit your page without JavaScript enabled, there is no content (except the text "A-hAAn") and no structured data.

Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool doesn’t run JavaScript when checking the markup.